# How to find the last saturday of current month in Python

Tags: python, date

I need some help with finding the last saturday of current month in Python. Now, this code run today show me Saturday 31th July, but I want to obtain Saturday 28th August.

```
off= (date.today().weekday() - 5)%7
Last_Saturday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=off)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last day of the month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: @quamrana hmm I look for the way for last Saturday of month

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from this question:
[Python: get last Monday of July 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796389/python-get-last-monday-of-july-2010)

You could do this to get the day of the month number, then do whatever you want with that

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

month = calendar.monthcalendar(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month)
day_of_month = max(month[-1][calendar.SATURDAY], month[-2][calendar.SATURDAY])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @quamrana answer you could do the following

```py
import calendar
if calendar.monthcalendar(2021, 8)[-1][5] != 0:
    print(calendar.monthcalendar(2021, 8)[-1][5])
else:
    print(calendar.monthcalendar(2021, 8)[-2][5])
```

**Output**

```sh
>>> if calendar.monthcalendar(2021, 8)[-1][5] != 0:
...     print(calendar.monthcalendar(2021, 8)[-1][5])
... else:
...     print(calendar.monthcalendar(2021, 8)[-2][5])
... 
28
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In whatever month we are, you can use this code to get the date corresponding to the last Saturday. 
Note that I considered only the last week of the month.
Inspiration came from [Percentage of Wednesdays ending months in the 21st Century](https://github.com/tem-ctrl/Wednesday_last_day_of_month)

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import calendar as cal

today = date.today()
month = today.month
year = today.year


length_month = cal.monthrange(year, month)[1]
for day in range(length_month,length_month-7,-1):
  if datetime(year, month, day).weekday()==5:
    last_saturday = datetime(year, month, day).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

print(f'Last Saturday of the current month : {last_saturday}')
```